# How to replace repeated values in a two-level list with a specific sequence ? (Python)

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
elements = 
[
[7, 3, 9, 6], 
[5, 7, 9, 6], 
[9, 8, 1, 4], 
[3, 9, 4, 7], 
]
```

It is necessary to replace the repeating values in each item with a sequence of numbers that begins with the maximum value in this list. and the sequence of replacement is also important, you need to change the numbers from lesser to greater. Thus, this list should look like

```
[
[7, 3, 9, 6], 
[5, 12, 14, 11], 
[15, 8, 1, 4], 
[10, 16, 4, 13], 
]
```

I tried to loop through the entire list, but my skills are not sufficient for this task

Comment: explain more precisely the logic of replacement

Comment: Why `4` remains unchanged in the last sublist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code iterates over each `sublist` in elements using a for loop, and creates an empty temporary list called `tmp` to store the modified version of the current `sublist`.

If the number is not in the `dic`, which means **it is not a duplicate**, it is simply appended to `tmp`. The number is also added to the `dic`, with its own value as the initial value.

If the number is already in `dic`, which means **it is a duplicate**, the code replaces the number with a new value that is the sum of the last value used to replace the number **(stored in the dic)** and the minimum value in the current `sublist`. The new value is then added to the `dic`.

**Code:**

```
elements = [[7, 3, 9, 6], [5, 7, 9, 6], [9, 8, 1, 4], [3, 9, 4, 7]]
res=[]
dic={}
for sublist in elements:
    tmp=[]
    for num in sublist:
        if num not in dic:
            tmp.append(num)
            dic[num]=num
        else:
            store=dic[num]+min(sublist)
            tmp.append(store)
            dic[num]=store
    res.append(tmp)
    
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[7, 3, 9, 6], [5, 12, 14, 11], [15, 8, 1, 4], [6, 18, 7, 15]]
```